# Find formula with Richardson Extrapolation based on centered difference formula

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, extrapolation

I'm preparing for my exams next week, and I'm making exercises as a preparation. Now, I'm asked to derive the following formula using Richardson Extrapolation based on the centered difference formula:

> Find this formula: $f'(x) = \frac{1}{12h}*(f(x - 2h) - 8f(x - h) + 8f(x + h) - f(x + 2h))$

The centered difference formula is this one:

> $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h}$

I'm given a solution telling me the following:

> $F(h) = f'(x) + a_1*h^2 + O(h^4) \\ F(2h) = f'(x) + a_1*(2h)^2+O(h^4) \\
>   4*F(h) - F(2h) = 3 * f'(x) + O(h^4)$

Now I'm not sure where this last equation comes from?

Comment: The last equation is a difference of the other, where the $F(h)$ equation is multipied by 4 to get rid of the $a_1 h^2$ terms in the difference.

Comment: Oh, ok! I should have seen that :) Thank you :)